# How to create pinch to zoom behaviour which snaps back when user releases the pinch (zoom that snaps back on release)?

Tags: android

I'm using `ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener()` to create "pinch to zoom" functionality in my Android app, but now the desired functionality is that it only zooms while the user is holding the pinch, and should revert back/snap back when they release.

I've seen this done in lots of apps, however I'm struggling to find any online documentation or other StackOverflow answers for how to do this.

I'm looking at my existing code, and I can see 2 places where I might have the logic:

- In my `ItemTouchListener` -> this is where I am passing the `TouchEvent` to my `ScaleDetector`. Could there be some logic here to do with `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` that resets everything?
- In my `SimpleOnScaleGestureListener()` -> is there anything clever I can do in `onScaleEnd` where I can find out from the `ScaleGestureDetector` that the user has released?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward, `onScaleEnd()` is called when the scale gesture finishes which makes sense. It's possible to reset things here, in my case it looks a little like this:

```
override fun onScaleEnd(detector: ScaleGestureDetector?) {
    view.scaleX = 1f
    view.scaleY = 1f
    view.invalidate()
}
```